# Using JB4A to handle rich notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, notification, push

I'm developing an app that already uses JB4A and I would like to include iOS 10 rich notifications support (saving the compatibility with older iOS versions, 8 and 9).

Among many articles and tutorials, I read also the following ones:
- https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/features/iOS10-notifications.html
- https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/rich-push/rich-push-overview.html

These articles don't mention neither the creation of a Service Extension (i.e. to download the image whose URL is provided in the payload) nor of a Content extension (i.e. to customise the UI of a notification).

The second article mentions the 'Cloud Page Messages' and the use of the 'ETWKLandingPagePresenter'. This class contains one method that uses a NSURL to load a web page (that could already contain some 'rich content' as text and image).

So I'm a little bit confused. Are the two approaches mutual exclusives (either I have to use Service Extension + content extension). What am I missing?

I'll appreciate also some working code that you could link.

Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 0):

@marcosciamanna,

Our Learning App sample project includes a Service Extension:

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppIos

For "rich notifications" you'd be implementing a service extension in your project, and relying on the Marketing Cloud sending a mutable-content attribute in the push payload.

We are piloting the "mutable-content" system right now within Salesforce Marketing Cloud; if you are interested you'd definitely want to contact your SFMC account executive/business representative to discuss your options.

Brian Criscuolo, Salesforce

Comment: Hi Brian, how is this "mutable-content" feature going so far? I kinda rely only on MarketingCloud to send push notifications, and need to add some info on the payload of the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Mutable content ("Rich Notifications") was enabled throughout MobilePush in our October 2017 release.

iOS release notes here: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/.